# Setting postgis on webfaction for geodjango

Tags: database, django, geodjango, webfaction

Im setting up my first geodjango app on webfaction and I was wondering if i can use the postgis back-end provided by webfaction( the one click setup) inside my virtualenv (im running the app inside a virtualenv).

Or do I have to install a new copy of postgresql with postgis extension and the inside the virtualenv?

Webfaction has all the supporting libraries installed already, so it would be convenient to use their database rather than installing everything. If I can use their database inside my virtualenv please guide as to how to setup.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried myself and you can use the webfaction database inside the virtualenv. Just configure it properly and you are good to go.